# wxPython - change the formatting and appearance of a grid object

Tags: python, formatting, grid, wxpython, appearance

I would like to know if it is possible to change the formatting of a grid object in wxPython.

Specifically I would like to know how to change the **background color, font type, font color, and border color of the header labels and the row labels**.

Here is a simple grid that I would like to change the formatting of:

```
 import wx
 import wx.grid as gridlib

 class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="A Simple Grid")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        myGrid.CreateGrid(12, 8)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First off, `wx.PySimpleApp` has been deprecated for a very long time and you really shouldn't use it any more. Use `wx.App` instead.

As for your question you would need to use `wx.lib.mixins.gridlabelrenderer`. The demo has an example in it called GridLabelRenderer that you can use. Basically you subclass `GridLabelRenderer` and modify its `Draw` method. Then you call each column's `SetColLabelRenderer` method and set it to use your custom renderer.